# Body constriction techniques

Tags: judo, chokes, pins, submissions

Judo shime-waza comprises three types of technique:

1. blood-chokes
2. air-chokes
3. body constrictions

The most famous of the third type is the (competition-banned) *do-jime*, but it is also possible to submit an opponent via a similar mechanism in a *kesa-gatame* hold.

Apart from these two shime-waza, are there any other body constriction techniques in judo?

Comment: To add: Knee-on-belly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are other constriction techniques. These are a few examples, not meant to be exhaustive. As a philosophical matter, I think you should always be looking to further break *uke's* structure and constrict their movement and breathing; this is maximum efficiency.

1. ***yoko shiho gatame*:** *Tori* is on the side with extended legs, one arm around the head, and the other arm through *uke's* legs high on the thigh grabbing *uke's* belt. *Tori* presses down with the chest on *uke's* chest while pulling both arms toward's *tori's* hips. The dual action increases pressure on *uke's* chest. This arm action is a common warmup drill where you lie face down on the mat and pull yourself across the mat using your arms but not legs, sometimes called chest pulls or *Mat putzen* (mat cleaning because it has the effect of sweeping the mat area).
2. ***kuzure tate shiho gatame*:** *Tori* ends up on top, with *tori's* left arm between *uke's* left arm and head, grabbing *uke's* belt behind *uke's* back. *Tori's* head helps to control *uke's* left arm and *tori's* right hand is free to brace against bridging. Constriction is most effective when *tori* traps *uke's* right arm across *uke's* body between *tori's* and *uke's* bodies. From this position, *tori* presses down with their chest while simultaneously pulling with the left hand belt grip.

   *Tori* can achieve this position by transitioning from a *kami shiho gatame* with both arms underneath *uke's* arms grabbing *uke's* belt. *Tori* then sits their left leg through on the right side and then steps over *uke's* body with the right leg to end up astride, maintaining the belt grip with their left hand throughout.
3. ***ushiro kesa gatame*:** this is very similar to *kesa gatame* in application, but I think this is even more effective in the reverse position. *Tori* twists while winding *uke's* arm and body to constrict.

I do not expect these constrictions to result in a submission or unconsciousness; they are more demoralizing and uncomfortable.

Comment: FWIW, when I teach holds in general, one of my maxims is that without being uncomfortable up to the point of tapping for uke, it is a bad hold. In tate-shiho position, I found it more effective to have my feet under uke's lower back and my hara on uke's arm/head, both for constriction/putting weight on them and for getting my hips off of theirs (less instable).

Answer (score 1):

The knee-on-belly variant of [uki-gatame](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9614/what-is-uki-gatame) can be used to submit uke by pressuring into their abdomen with the knee while pulling their jacket towards you.